# Integrate custom java web application with MS dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, integration, custom-application

Currently we have custom java application which is connected to salesforce CRM via canvas integration. Now we need to integrate with MS dynamics CRM.

Could you please tell me high level steps? how authentication will happen when control come from dynamics to custom application? Is there any canvas integration / iframe like thing in ms dynamics?

Comment: You can put an iframe on a dashboard or a form or even sitemap in Dynamics CRM, google has plenty of tutorials of that

Answer (score 0):

The best thing for a non .Net Application is to use the [Dynamics 365 WebApi](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt593051.aspx)

It supports all common types of CRM Instances (On-Premise, Online) and authentication Methods:

- OAuth (2)
- Office365
- AD
- etc...

You can than look for existing projects on the web. ([Like this guide for example](https://www.fmtconsultants.com/connect-java-application-crm-simple-java-console-application/))

Comment: We have one custom java application which is accessible over internet. We want to access this from dynamics as iframe by passing username and some other parameters to that url. so how can we do it?